# MVC2 and Google Custom Search

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, google-custom-search

I am trying to incorporate google custom search in my MVC2 application. I have already registered for google custom search and obtained API key and other settings. I have an input type textbox on my view and a search button. How can now i pass the search string (from my textbox) to google API and receive the search result and show them on same or other view page? any related post, example would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Implementing Search in ASP.NET width Google Custom Search](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Implementing-Search-in-ASP-NET-with-Google-Custom-Search.aspx) looks like a pretty good match. As long as you don't do his conversion of the form markup Google provides to the `form runat="server"` webforms style markup it should work fine in an MVC context.